# 'Unexpected symbol 'void' expecting ; { => or where' Unity2D Tower Defense game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to create a Unity2D tower defense game, and there seems to be a problem with 'Unexpected symbol 'void' expecting ; {  => or where'  after the 'string[] LoadLevelText (int i)' (Line 71). I'm following a tutorial and I did exactly everything, but this one error doesn't seem to be fixable, as it just rises more problems.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class LvlManagerScr : MonoBehaviour {


    public int fieldWidth, fieldHeight;

    public GameObject cellPref;
    public Transform cellParent;

    public Sprite[] tileSpr = new Sprite[2];

    public List<GameObject> wayPoints = new List<GameObject>();
    GameObject[,] allCells = new GameObject[10, 22];

    int currWayX, currWayY;
    GameObject firstCell;


    void Start () {
        CreateLevel();
        LoadWaypoints();
    }

    void CreateLevel()
    {
        Vector3 worldVec = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, Screen.height, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldHeight; i++)
            for(int k = 0; k < fieldWidth; k++)
            {
                int sprIndex = int.Parse(LoadLevelText(1)[i].ToCharArray()[k].ToString());
                Sprite spr = tileSpr[sprIndex];

                bool isGround = spr == tileSpr[1] ? true : false;

                CreateCell(isGround, spr, k, i, worldVec);
            }
    }

    void CreateCell(bool isGround, Sprite spr, int x, int y, Vector3 wV)
    {
        GameObject tmpCell = Instantiate(cellPref);
        tmpCell.transform.SetParent(cellParent, false);

        tmpCell.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spr;

        float sprSizeX = tmpCell.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
        float sprSizeY = tmpCell.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y;

        tmpCell.transform.position = new Vector3 (wV.x + (sprSizeX * x), wV.y + (sprSizeY * -y));

        if (isGround)

        {
            tmpCell.GetComponent<CellScr>().isGround = true;

            if (firstCell == null)
            {
                firstCell = tmpCell;
                currWayX = x;
                currWayY = y;
            }
        }

        allCells[y, x] = tmpCell;

    }


    string[] LoadLevelText (int i)

    void LoadWaypoints()
    {
        GameObject currWay60;
        wayPoints.Add(firstCell);

        while (true) 
        {
            currWay60 = null;

            if (currwayX > 0 && allCells [currWayY, currWayX - 1].GetComponent<CellScr> ().isGround &&
               !wayPoints.Exists (x => x == allCells [currWayY, currWayX - 1])) 
            {
                currWay60 = allCells [currWayY, currWayX - 1];
                currWayX--;
                Debug.Log ("Next Cell is Left");
            } 
            else if (currwayX < 0 (fieldWidth - 1) && allCells [currWayY, currWayX + 1].GetComponent<CellScr> ().isGround &&
                    !wayPoints.Exists (x => x == allCells [currWayY, currWayX - 1])) 
            {
                currWay60 = allCells [currWayY, currWayX + 1];
                currWayX++;
                Debug.Log ("Next Cell is Right");
            } 
            else if (currWayY > 0 && allCells [currwayY - 1, currWayX].GetComponent<CellScr> ().isGround &&
                     !wayPoints.Exists (x => x == allCells [currWayY - 1, currWayX])) 
            {
                currWay60 = allCells [currWayY - 1, currWayX];
                currWayY--;
                Debug.Log ("Next Cell is Up");
            } 
            else if (currWayY < 0 (fieldHeight - 1) && allCells [currwayY + 1, currWayX].GetComponent<CellScr> ().isGround &&
                     !wayPoints.Exists (x => x == allCells [currWayY - 1, currWayX])) 
            {
                currWay60 = allCells [currWayY + 1, currWayX];
                currWayY++;
                Debug.Log ("Next Cell is Down");
            } 
            else
                break;

            wayPoints.Add (currWay60);

        }

    }               
}
```

In the tutorial there seems to be a box with an ellipsis in it:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Copy and post **everything** from that script. This will help people spot the error for you.

Comment: The `LoadLevelText ` method is missing a body.

Comment: (… and most of the lines in your code block, especially the last two, are missing another four blanks of indent.) (Welcome to SO! (And its funny markup))

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
string[] LoadLevelText (int i)
```

looks incomplete!

Try replacing it with following to see to see if it works for now:

```
string[] LoadLevelText(int i)
{
   return null;
}
```

You probably will need to figure out what LoadLevelText() is supposed to be doing in order to complete your code.